# How do you drag a Button from the toolbox to a UserControl in a Class Library?

Tags: dotnetnuke-7

I am unable to drag a button or any standard control from the toolbox in VS2013 onto the User Control View.ASCX generated using the DotNetNuke 7 C# Compiled Module template.

Template installation guide:
http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/2

Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/discussions/355503

> hc27080401 Jan 11, 2014 at 9:02 AM
>
> I find that may be template problem,open the project
>   file(.csproj),change the output path from "....\bin\" to "bin\", it
>   will works